# REGEX expression for consecutive characters

Tags: regex, dfa

I have been stuck on this regular expression for the past two hours. 
How would you write a regex in which every pair of consecutive ’E’s occurs before every pair of consecutive ’O’s. For instance, your DFA should accept the strings “GOODBOY”, “FEEDME”, “HELLO” and “FEEDMEGOOD” but not “LOOKITSDEEP”.

I am quite new to regex and I am using a modern html regex machine.

As for what I've tried so far, I know that it will accept 4 cases:

- case 1: there are no EE's or OO's
- case 2: there is an OO but no EE
- case 3: There is an EE but no OO
- case 4: there is an EE before an OO

However, it does not accept the following case:

- case 5: if there is a OO before an EE.

What I've tried to do is do a 'not' case with case number 5 and what I've come up with is:

```
[^[A-Z]*(OO)+[A-Z]*(EE)+]
```

However, this does not seem to work :(

help would really be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please show us some of the stuff you've tried.

Comment: If you've been *stuck...for the past two hours*, it would seem to me that you would at least have a few of your efforts that haven't worked to include in your question, no? When you [edit] to include them, you might also include information on what regex engine you're using, as different engines have different capabilities and syntax differences.

Comment: I have added my work!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, trying to match the "should not" case and inverting the result.  It's mainly the syntax you're missing.  Here's how I would do it:

```
^(?!.*OO.*EE)[A-Z]*$
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead; it means "if it's possible to match this expression at this point, fail."  The `^` anchors the match at the beginning of the string; without that, the regex engine will keep trying to match starting at every consecutive position.  The `[A-Z]*$` ensures that the string consists entirely of capital letters.